# Please be mindful of non-programming and development question migrations

Tags: discussion, bug, migration

Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question was recently migrated to Stack Overflow even though it has nothing to do with programming and development: [Create matrix from binary string using Octave](https://superuser.com/questions/1392903/create-matrix-from-binary-string-using-octave).

The question was a simple *"how do I use `<program>`"*. It meets two criteria from the [Help Center | On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic):

- computer software, or
- personal and home computer networking

Please be mindful during migrations.

Answer (score 8):

#### This question was recently migrated to Stack Overflow even though it has nothing to do with programming and development.

I have to disagree.

> **GNU Octave is a high-level language**, primarily intended for numerical computations. It is typically used for such problems as solving linear and nonlinear equations, numerical linear algebra, statistical analysis, and for performing other numerical experiments. **It may also be used as a batch-oriented language for automated data processing**."

Source [GNU Octave: Introduction](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.3/Introduction.html#Introduction)

And tag [octave](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/octave) says:

> GNU Octave is a mathematical software package and **scripting language**. The scripting language is intended to be compatible with [matlab](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/matlab), and the two packages are almost entirely consistent.

It sure looks like a programming language to me.

That makes writing  programs in Octave on topic on StackOverflow.

In addition, StackoverFlow has more than **3750** questions with tag [octave](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/octave). That **surely** makes it on topic.

If they really aren't on topic then you need to close all of those questions and not single out a single migrated programming question.

Comment: Really? How do you think interpreters work? Hint: they use a scripting language to parse input.